# Transition not showing for animated polarbar plot with plotly (offline)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to make a polar barplot rotate smoothly using plotly in offline mode. Following the [examples available in the docs](https://plot.ly/python/animations/), I do this by creating a button with as method "animate" and setting the transition time to a value >0 ms.

The same problem occurred when using a scatterpolar type plot instead of a barplot, however the animation did work for a non-polar type scatter plot.

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
offline.init_notebook_mode()

#some data to plot:
df = pd.DataFrame({'artist':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
                            'birth': pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['1990-04-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1945-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '1955-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1956-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '1976-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1930-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '1942-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1936-11-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '1971-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1952-12-01T00:00:00.000000000'])), 
                            'death': pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2012-04-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '2010-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '2016-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '2010-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2015-11-01T00:00:00.000000000',
                                      '2014-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2013-12-01T00:00:00.000000000']))} )

#creating the barplot:
shift = df['birth'] - pd.datetime(1970, 1 ,1) 
trace = {
    'name': "to", 
    'r': (df['death']- shift).dt.date, 
    'theta': np.linspace(0,360,11),
    'base':df['birth'].dt.date,
    'type': 'barpolar'
}
data = [trace]

nsteps = 20
tracedicts = [] 
start_thetas = np.linspace(0,360,nsteps)
for i in start_thetas:
    tracedicts.append(trace.copy())
    tracedicts[-1]['theta'] = np.linspace(i,360+i,11)

frames = [{'data': [tracei]} for tracei in tracedicts]

layout = {
    'polar':{
        'angularaxis':{
            'visible': False,
        },
        'radialaxis':{  
            'showgrid': True,
            'type': 'date',
            'hoverformat': '%m-%Y',
        }
    },
    'updatemenus': [{
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'y': 0,
        'buttons':[{'label':'Play', 'method':'animate',
                    'args':[None, {'frame':{'duration':600, 'redraw':True}, 
                                   'transition':{'duration':400},
                                   'fromcurrent':True,
                                   'easing': 'linear'}]}]
    }],
} 

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout, frames = frames)
offline.iplot(fig,auto_play=False)
```

The animation works as far as showing the different frames, but the transition does not work. 
Is this a feature that simply does not exist for all polar and/or bar plots?

(You'll also notice that I set `'redraw':True` - this is because otherwise the animation only worked when setting `auto_play=True` at the end.)

Comment: Unfortunately we do not yet support transitions for anything other than scatter plots.

Comment: Ah, pity. Any plans for changing that in the near future? Would it be useful if I open a feature request issue for this? And thans for your quick answer!

Comment: We have the issue open and we plan to address it but I can't commit to any timeline at the moment, sorry :)